# Cannot yield elements of matrix C#

Tags: c#, matrix

I have a class Matrix. I create objects of Matrix m1 and m2. Then using IEnumerable method I want to summarize all elements of matrix. So when I want to yield all elements of m1 object. It says me:

`The name 'm1' does not exist in the current context`

So how to yield elements of m1 matrix object???

```
public static Random randDouble = new Random();

public static void Main()
{
    Matrix m1 = new Matrix();
    Matrix m2 = new Matrix();

    InitMatrix(m1);
    InitMatrix(m2);
    List<Matrix> matrices = new List<Matrix>();
    matrices.Add(m1);
    matrices.Add(m2);
    int r = 0;
    foreach (int v in GridValues())
    {
        r += v;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> GridValues()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            yield return m1[x, y];
}

public static void InitMatrix(Matrix mat)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            mat[i, j] = randDouble.NextDouble();
}
```

Comment: m1 is not accessible from your `GridValues` method as it is a local variable from the `Main` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `m1` is a local variable from the `Main` function, so it is not accessible in `GridValues`.

You could send `m1` as a parameter to your `GridValues` function.

And there is also the fact that your `Matrix` seems to contain `double` and not `int` values.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Matrix m1 = new Matrix();
    Matrix m2 = new Matrix();

    InitMatrix(m1);
    InitMatrix(m2);
    List<Matrix> matrices = new List<Matrix>();
    matrices.Add(m1);
    matrices.Add(m2);
    double r = 0;
    foreach (double v in GridValues(m1))
    {
        r += v;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}

public static IEnumerable<double> GridValues(Matrix m)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            yield return m[x, y];
}
```